# How to add jinja2 extensions to python bottle

Tags: python, jinja2, bottle

I want to add the minify html extension found [here](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2-htmlcompress) to the Jinja2Template in bottle.

In bottle.py I've gotten as far as changing the line

`self.env = Environment(loader=FunctionLoader(self.loader), **kwargs)`

to

`self.env = Environment(loader=FunctionLoader(self.loader), extensions=['jinja2htmlcompress.HTMLCompress'], **kwargs)`

It doesn't know where to get the extension so I get this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'jinja2htmlcompress'",)

How do I make the module available?

Comment: maybe you have to put `jinja2htmlcompress.py` in the same folder as you have your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

furas was right. I just put jinja2htmlcompress.py in the same folder as bottle.py and it worked.

You can also add a model directory to your project with an an empty __init__.py file and any extension files you want to use (in my case jinja2htmlcompress.py). Then add `from model import jinja2hmtlcompress`
to bottle.py